# Same dataset outputs different characters : phpmyadmin / own query

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

Im trying to get a some data from the db , but the output isn't what i expected.
Doing my own querying on the db , i get this output : `string 'C�te d�Ivoire' (length=13)`

Querying the db from phpmyadmin i get normal output : Côte d’Ivoire

php.ini default charset, mysql db default charset , `<meta>` charset are all set to utf-8 .

I can't fugire it out where the encoding is being made that i get different output with same configuration .

P.S. : using mysqli driver .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same page that gives you wrong results, try first running this instruction

```
print base64_encode("Côte");
```

The correct answer is `Q8O0dGU...`. If you get something else, like `Q/R0ZQo...`, this means that your script is working with another charset (here Latin-1) instead of UTF-8. It's still possible that *also* MySQL and *also* the browser are playing tricks, but the line above **ensures** that PHP and/or your editor are playing you false.

Next, extract `Côte` from the database and output its `base64_encode`. If you see `Q8O0...`, then the connection between MySQL and PHP is safely UTF8. If not, then whatever else might *also* be needed, you need to change the MySQL charset (`SET NAMES utf8` and/or `ALTER` of table and database collation).

If PHP is UTF8, and MySQL is UTF8, and *still* you see invalid characters, then it's something between PHP and the browser. Verify that the content type header is sent correctly; if not, try sending it yourself as first thing in the script:

```
Header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8');
```

For example in Apache configuration you should have

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Verify also that your browser is not set to *override* both server charset and auto-detection.

**NOTE**: as a rule of thumb, if you get **a single diamond with a question mark** instead of a UTF8 international character, this means that an UTF8 reader received an invalid UTF8 code point. In other words, the entity showing the diamond (your browser) is expecting UTF8, but is receiving something else, for example Latin1 a.k.a. ISO-8859-15.

**Another** difficult-to-track way of getting that error is if the output somehow *contains a byte order mark (BOM)*. This may happen if you create a file such as

```
###<?php
    Header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF8");
?>
<html>
     <head>
         <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8" />
     </head>
     <body>
         Hellò, world!
     </body>
</html>
```

where that ### is an (invisible in most editors) UTF8 BOM. To remove it, you either need to save the file as "without BOM" if the editor allows it, or use a different editor.

Comment: Yes it was from the db server side . I've set the charset for the db but didnt work . Now i've set it on server start and it works . Thought it also works by seting it only for a db. Ty for your help .

Answer (score 0):

If you do your "own querying" with the command line tool mysql, you have to set the option `--default-character-set=utf8`, too. Otherwise, please tell us how you do your own querying.

Comment: Like i said in the P.S. using mysli driver (this is what i was refering to own querying)... using phpmyadmin as a tool for mysql .